# XmlSerializer ignoring GetObjectData() from ISerializable

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I want to serialize and deserialize immutable object to XML. How can I achieve that with XmlSerializer?

I've already implemented ISerializable interface and method GetObjectData from it but XmlSerializer is ignoring it. Apparently, when converting to JSON via Newtonsoft.Json everything is fine. I know that I can possibly achieve that by refactoring code to DataContractSerializer but I'd like to keep existing XmlSerializer in the solution. The structure of my immutable object is defined below.

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomerNumberDefinition : ISerializable
{
    private CustomerNumberDefinition()
    {
    }

    private CustomerNumberDefinition(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext text)
        : this()
    {
        this.KlpUserNumber = info.GetString(nameof(this.KlpUserNumber));
        this.RawCustomerNumber = info.GetString(nameof(this.RawCustomerNumber));
    }

    private CustomerNumberDefinition(string customerNumber, string klpUserNumber)
    {
        this.RawCustomerNumber = customerNumber;
        this.KlpUserNumber = klpUserNumber;
    }

    public string KlpUserNumber { get; }

    public string RawCustomerNumber { get; }

    public static CustomerNumberDefinition Create(string customerNumber, string klpUserNumber)
    {
        return new CustomerNumberDefinition(customerNumber, klpUserNumber);
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(this.KlpUserNumber), this.KlpUserNumber);
        info.AddValue(nameof(this.RawCustomerNumber), this.RawCustomerNumber);
    }
}
```

I expect that when trying to serialize an instance of CustomerNumberDefinition class via XmlSerializer, GetObjectData() will be invoked but it's not happening.

Comment: `ISerializable` is nothing to do with `XmlSerializer` - it isn't even remotely interested in that API; there *is* a custom xml serialization API, but frankly, I really really don't recommend ever implementing it...

Comment: from a serialization perspective, personally I think you're solving the wrong problem here; in my experience, **the moment** it becomes awkward to serialize your domain model in a particular serializer, the best thing to do is: *stop doing that*: instead, create a second model that is simple and exists *just* to fit the serializer - so, in this case mutable and basic; then map between that model and the *real* model before/after (de)serialization. This is pragmatic advice that solves 98%+ of all complex serialization problems.